# Messages lost in ROS ELECTRIC

Tags: ros, ros-electric, topics, messages, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why do certain message packets get lost?
Is this normal?
I have attached a image for reference. Clearly, packets 0,1,2 were lost.

Please help
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34264/messages-lost-in-ros-electric/) by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2012-05-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-14**:
This problem is similar to another one, which also detailed solutions: http://answers.ros.org/question/11167/how-do-i-publish-exactly-one-message/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You lose only the first few messages. This probably doesn't have anything to do with buffer sizes but that subscribing takes a while. Your publisher node always publishes something although the connection to your subscriber is not completely established yet. This behavior directly follows from the way ros works.

Normally nodes are written in a way that this doesn't matter. However, roscpp provides callbacks when nodes subscribe or unsubscribe (connect_cb and disconnect_cb as shown [here](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a2d81fe5562417931bd7634490c364473)) and you can get the [number of subscribed nodes](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Publisher.html#ad56c8e954020290dcb87cd6bbd330a2b) from the publisher object. That way, the publisher can start publishing only when the subscriber is present.

Latched topics are used more commonly though. With a latched topic, the subscriber always receives the newest message that has been published right after the connection to the publisher is established.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2012-05-20**:
This definitely seems to be the case, not the queue stuff I mention in my answer. :)

**Comment by [Meet H Thakkar](https://answers.ros.org/users/24239/meet-h-thakkar/) on 2020-03-06**:
you can also look at https://answers.ros.org/question/341005/message-delivery-guarantees-in-ros1/